# CSS validation with AntiSamy

Tags: java, antisamy

I have a String, and I want to validate whether it is a valid CSS value or not. In the documentation of AntiSamy, I found that I might be able to use CSSValidator.isValidProperty (http://javadox.com/org.owasp/antisamy/1.4/org/owasp/validator/css/CssValidator) to do so. However, the type of the second param requires LexicalUnit.

Is there another way to validate a String with AnitSamy?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the CssScanner.

```
/****** pull out style tag from html *****/
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<style>([\\s\\S]+?)</style>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(validHTML);

// if we find a match, get the group 
if (m.find()) {

// get the matching group
    codeGroup = m.group(1);
}
/****** block for checking all css for validity *****/

InternalPolicy policy = null;
try {
    policy = (InternalPolicy) InternalPolicy.getInstance("antisamy-ebay.xml");
} catch (PolicyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("AntiSamy", Locale.getDefault());

CssScanner scanner = new CssScanner(policy, messages);
CleanResults results = scanner.scanStyleSheet(codeGroup, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
validCSS = results.getCleanHTML().toString();
```

That is the part of the code that worked for me. Let me know if any of this does not work for you, I have variables declared at the top of the code because I am also handling html validation in here too. So some variables are not in this code. But it should point you in the right direction. Also, you need a policy in place, I chose the ebay policy, this guides the whitelist of what the css will allow for the resulting output. I have not used the CssValidator, so I am not sure how they compare, but CssScanner does a great job of giving back clean css.